# Retrieving rows from a SQL Server table which has same value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, self-join

I have the following table:

```
Vehicle_no  DEA_id      Name       location
--------------------------------------------
1030        T100024     xxxxx      Canada
1012        T103125     yyyyy      America
1045        T100024     xxxxx      Canada
```

I want to retrieve the first row and the rows which have the same dealer id. For the above example, the result I want to get is row1 and row3...

How can I do that in SQL Server? I tried by left join with same table. But I am not getting the result as I expected.

```
SELECT  *
FROM ODS.MKT_DEALER_GET AS t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 1 * 
     FROM ODS.MKT_DEALER_GET) AS t2 ON t.[DEA_id] = ts.[DEA_id]
```

Please help me to solve this. My database is SQL Server

Comment: There is no such thing as "first row".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you care about ordering, you need a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  To identify the "first" row you need a column that specifies the ordering.  I would write this using `=` rather than a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT dg.*
FROM ODS.MKT_DEALER_GET dg
WHERE dg.DEA_id = (SELECT TOP 1 dg2.DEA_id
                   FROM ODS.MKT_DEALER_GET dg2
                   ORDER BY ?
                  );
```

Or, if you have other information, use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT dg.*
FROM ODS.MKT_DEALER_GET dg
WHERE dg.DEA_id = (SELECT TOP 1 dg2.DEA_id
                   FROM ODS.MKT_DEALER_GET dg2
                   WHERE Vehicle_no = 1030
                  );
```